# How to create an object from 2 arrays?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, arrays, object

So I hava array `Links` and array `Params` with same langth `N`

So what I need is to create an object where for each `link` from `Links` I will be able to see 
  `param` from `Params`

And than for example to be abble to call  something like

```
for each( item in object) 
if (item.param == "some value") {
// some code
} else...
```

How to do such thing (Code exaMple, please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Array](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Array.html#push()): You could first build a list with elements composed of a item and a param (supposing the length is indeed the same for both lists)

```
var items:Array = new Array();

for(var i:uint = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
   links:Array .push({link:links[i], param:params[i]});
}
```

You can then filter them easily:

```
items.forEach(checkValue);

for(var i:uint = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if (items[i].param == "some value") {
    // some code
  } else{
    ...
  }
}
```